# Calculate the frequency of classes of neighbouring raster cells

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, statistics

I'm struggling with a problem when working with a raster dataset of biotope types:

For each cell I would like to find out the frequency of classes in the adjacent cells, e.g. from the 8 neighbouring cells 3 are of biotope type A, 4 of type B and 1 cell of type C.

I was recommended to try out 'Block Statistics' and work with a moving window, but so without any success.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [tour].  What precisely did you try in terms of 'Block Statistics'?

Answer (score 2):

The result, however it happens to be stored or presented to you, evidently will be the equivalent of one raster for each class: a raster showing the counts of type "A", another showing the counts of type "B", and so on.

Compute these count grids by taking [focal statistics](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/focal-statistics.htm) of the indicator grids.

Recall that the indicator for any class is a grid having ones for cells where the class exists and zeros elsewhere.  Create indicators by equating the original grid with the individual class values.  The *focal sum* over a 3 x 3 annular neighborhood (that is, omitting the center) thereby counts the cells of that type.  (If you don't want to compute a focal sum for annular neighborhoods--finding it perhaps easier to compute the full 3 x 3 focal sum--simply subtract each indicator from its 3 x 3 focal sum!)

You have to iterate this workflow over all class types.